# Making a particle system more "fluffy"

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

I currently have a rug using hair particles that looks something like this.

[image]

What can I tweak to get it look more like the rug shown below?

[image]

Comment: Your hair probably needs more subdivisions and higher particle count with thinner strands

Comment: Ok, I already have a lot of particles but I'll try that out tomorrow. Thanks.